# Cumulocity CEP Event Query depending on other event

Tags: complex-event-processing, cumulocity

I have an event that is triggered when a device starts a process with a unique process id. 
When the process stops it sends another event with its Timestamp and the same process id.
Now I want to calculate the total process time. So subtract the Timestamp from the Startevent from the Timestamp from the Endevent.

I tried multiple ways to accomplish this but they all failed.

Is it possible to save an item from a query to a variable?
e.g. 
select 
  @var = d.ProcessID
from table d

or is it possible to make subqueries??
e.g. 
select 
  d.TimeStamp
from table d
where d.ProcessID = (select
                      e.ProcessID
                     from table e)

Or if anyone has a different suggestion it would be great to have some input :)

Thanks in advance
Greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use patterns to achieve this. Something like that might work:

```
select * from pattern [every a=StartEvent -> b=StopEvent(sourceId = a.sourceId, processId = a.processId)]
```

For more info have a look at the [Esper](http://esper.espertech.com/release-5.5.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#pattern-logical-every) doc.